# When does the Fourier transform of a measure vanish at a point?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

Given a finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbf{R}$, consider its Fourier transform which is defined as:

$$\hat{\mu}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbf{R}} e^{2\pi i x \xi} \, d\mu(x). $$

Two questions about this:

1. Suppose that $\int_{\mathbf{R}} x^n \, d\mu(x) = 0$ for some $n \geq 1$. Can we show that there exists a $\xi \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $\hat{\mu}(\xi) = 0$?
2. More generally, is there a sufficient condition we can place on the measure $\mu$ that ensures that there exists a point $\xi \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $\hat{\mu}(\xi)=0$? For example, is there some multiplicative function $f(x)$ such that if $\int_{\mathbf{R}} f(x) \, d\mu(x) = 0$, then there must exist $\xi \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $\hat{\mu}(\xi)=0$?

Comment: A counterexample for #1: $\mu(S) = \int_S \exp(-x^2)\, d\mu_L$ gives $\int_\mathbf{R} x^n\, d\mu(x) = 0$ for every odd $n$, but $\hat\mu(\xi) = \sqrt{\pi} \exp(-\pi^2 \xi^2) \neq 0$.

Comment: #2 has "trivial" examples like $f(x) = \exp(2\pi i x \xi_0)$ and $\int_{\mathbf{R}} f(x)\, d\mu(x) = 0$ implies $\hat\mu(\xi_0) = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has already been pointed out in comments that 1. does not hold.

Concerning 2, the equation $\hat{\mu}(\xi_0)=0$ is equivalent to
$$\tag{1}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(\xi-\xi_0)\hat{\mu}(\xi)\, d\xi=0. $$
Using the property $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\hat{g}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}g$, we see that (1) is equivalent to
$$
\tag{2}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{2\pi ix \xi_0}\, d\mu(x)=0.$$
Thus the answer to 2. is: $\hat{\mu}$ vanishes at $\xi_0$ if and only if (2) holds.

P.S.: Only now I realized that [aschepler](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4584863/when-does-the-fourier-transform-of-a-measure-vanish-at-a-point/4584913#comment9652210_4584863) had already mentioned this in a comment.

Comment: I am glad this has been upvoted, but it is really quite trivial. The equation (2) is just a rewriting of $\hat{\mu}(\xi_0)=0$. When this happens, it is because the question asked is not really the "right" one as it allows for trivial solutions. I don't know what the right question is, however.